# Gift Certificate / Gift Voucher / Discount codes

Tags: php, codeigniter, discount

can anyone please tell me the difference between **Gift Certificate , Gift Voucher and Discount codes** ?

I need to implement Gift Voucher functionality in Codeigniter but I am not sure what is difference between these three .

Any suggestion is Appreciated.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about the definition of English words

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a question you should be asking here as it does not pertain to coding, but ill give you a link that gives you a pretty good description: http://tips.thinkrupee.com/articles/what-is-gift-voucher-gift-certificate-.php

also if you would like to incorporate these three in CI, i would just create a function in your controller for each of these. if you only are interested in gift voucher then i would try something like this:

```
function buyGiftVoucher(){
 ..your code..
}

function useGiftVoucher(){
  ..your code
}
```

hope this helps a bit